# generate unique ID for on foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

Current I use toggle to show/hide details. I need to give each div a unique ID in foreach loop. I'm not sure how to make it works on an echo string. Can you help me?

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
    foreach ( $payment as $payment_id => $items ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $i++;
            $count = 0;
            // Echo, need to show unique ID in both $count, it must be the same
            echo '<p><strong><a href="#">Link</a></strong>
            <br/><a href="#" class="show_info" id="'.$count.'">Show Details</a>
            <div id="payment_info_'.$count.'" style="display:none;">';
            ++count;
        }
    }
?>
```

I need to make $count in 2 position on the code is same. I got error with this code.

### Thank you

Updated:
Actually the code is not just as I give here. I tried with your code but doesnt work.

You can view full at http://www.codesend.com/view/7d58acb2b1c51149440984ec6568183d/ (pasw:123123)

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: move ` $count = 0;` out side the loop, inside you set it to 0 every time

Answer (score 1):

1. You've writen `++count` instead of `++$count`
2. It seems you're not using `$i`.
3. You're initializing `$count` on every loop.

This is supposed to work:

```
<?php
$i = 0; /* Seems redundant */
$count = 0;
    foreach ( $payment as $payment_id => $items ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $i++; /* Seems redundant */
            // Echo, need to show unique ID in both $count, it must be the same
            echo '<p><strong><a href="#">Link</a></strong>
            <br/><a href="#" class="show_info" 
                    id="dtls'.$count.'">Show Details</a>
            <div id="payment_info_'.$count.'" style="display:none;">';
            ++$count;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually the code is not just as I give here. I tried with your code but doesnt work.

You can view full at http://www.codesend.com/view/7d58acb2b1c51149440984ec6568183d/ (pasw:123123)

Comment: @TKien : **1.** Are you getting an `error`, or it's just `not working` as you expect? If it's an error, please copy it here. If your code doesn't give an error but just not working, you should copy the output HTML to a site like http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can see what's the problem in it. **2.** Notice that on the last `if` in your loop, your calling two `count()` functions. This will recalculate on every `loop run`, so it's better if you calculate them before the loop and save them on two `variables`.

Comment: Its wordpress plugin code. It works fine but the count is not jumb, I see all the ID is 1. Like this image http://i6.upanh.com/2013/0817/08//57199065.817201332840pm.png

Answer (score 0):

**first:**

remove this or put it outside of the foreach loop :

```
$count = 0;
```

**second:**

don't use only number for **id** and use it with a character or word like this :

```
id = "element'.$count.'"
```

**Third :**

what is `$i` ?

if it's useless remove it!

**Forth**

change `++count` to `++$count`

**CODE :**

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
$count = 0;
    foreach ( $payment as $payment_id => $items ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $i++;
            // Echo, need to show unique ID in both $count, it must be the same
            echo '<p><strong><a href="#">Link</a></strong>
            <br/><a href="#" class="show_info" id="info_'.$count.'">Show Details</a>
            <div id="payment_info_'.$count.'" style="display:none;">';
            ++$count;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually the code is not just as I give here. I tried with your code but doesnt work.

You can view full at http://www.codesend.com/view/7d58acb2b1c51149440984ec6568183d/ (pasw:123123)

Answer (score 0):

**++count** is wrong, it should be ++$count;

try this

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
    foreach ( $payment as $payment_id => $items ) {
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $i++;
            $count = 0;
            // Echo, need to show unique ID in both $count, it must be the same
            echo '<p><strong><a href="#">Link</a></strong>
            <br/><a href="#" class="show_info" id="'.$count.'">Show Details</a>
            <div id="payment_info_'.$count.'" style="display:none;">';
            ++$count;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually the code is not just as I give here. I tried with your code but doesnt work.

You can view full at http://www.codesend.com/view/7d58acb2b1c51149440984ec6568183d/ (pasw:123123)